# How to draw image below boxes on a Vaadin canvas?

Tags: java, canvas, vaadin, drawimage

I currently have a canvas where I will first draw an image before all the other canvas mouse-draw functions come in (to draw the boxes). I also have an undo function which will remove the last drawn box, clear the entire canvas and redraw all the remaining boxes back onto the canvas. However, after undoing, the image will somehow appear on top of the boxes and covering them, instead of below as it should be. I was able to fix this using z-index in HTML5 previously, but do not know how to do so using the Java way.

This is my Canvas.java (undo method is towards the end):

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.HasSize;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.HasStyle;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.dom.Element;
import com.vaadin.flow.dom.ElementFactory;
import com.vaadin.flow.shared.Registration;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.backend.MainLayout;
import elemental.json.JsonObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Canvas component that you can draw shapes and images on. It's a Java wrapper
 * for the
 * <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API">HTML5
 * canvas</a>.
 * <p>
 * Use {@link #getContext()} to get API for rendering shapes and images on the
 * canvas.
 * <p>
 */
@Tag("canvas")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Canvas extends Component implements HasStyle, HasSize {

    private static CanvasRenderingContext2D context;
    private Element element;
    private boolean mouseSelect = false;
    private boolean mouseIsDown = false;
    private double endX;
    private double endY;
    public static int boxCount = 0;
    public static boolean undoCalled = false;

    public static ArrayList <BoundingBox> arrayBoxes = new ArrayList<BoundingBox>();
    public static ArrayList <MousePosition> mousePosArray = new ArrayList<MousePosition>();
    public static ArrayList <SelectBox> selectBoxes = new ArrayList<SelectBox>();
    private List<Runnable> mouseMoveListeners = new ArrayList<>(0);

    public static ArrayList<BoundingBox> getArrayBoxes() {
        return arrayBoxes;
    }

    public static ArrayList<MousePosition> getMousePosArray() {
        return mousePosArray;
    }

    public static void setMousePosArray(ArrayList<MousePosition> mousePosArray) {
        Canvas.mousePosArray = mousePosArray;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new canvas component with the given size.
     * <p>
     * Use the API provided by {@link #getContext()} to render graphics on the
     * canvas.
     * <p>
     * The width and height parameters will be used for the canvas' coordinate
     * system. They will determine the size of the component in pixels, unless
     * you explicitly set the component's size with {@link #setWidth(String)} or
     * {@link #setHeight(String)}.
     *
//     * @param width
//     *            the width of the canvas
//     * @param height
//     *            the height of the canvas
//     */

    public Registration addMouseMoveListener(Runnable listener) {
        mouseMoveListeners.add(listener);
        return () -> mouseMoveListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public Canvas(int width, int height) {

        context = new CanvasRenderingContext2D(this);

        context.drawImage("https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2016/10/Red-Clouds-and-Prairie-Background.jpg", 0, 0);

        element = getElement();
        element.getStyle().set("border", "1px solid");

        getElement().setAttribute("width", String.valueOf(width));
        getElement().setAttribute("height", String.valueOf(height));

        element.addEventListener("mousedown", event -> {  // Retrieve Starting Position on MouseDown

            Element boundingBoxResult = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult);

            JsonObject evtData = event.getEventData();

            double xBox = evtData.getNumber("event.x");
            double yBox = evtData.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-x", String.format("%f", xBox));
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-y", String.format("%f", yBox));

            BoundingBox newBox = new BoundingBox("","", xBox, yBox, 0.0, 0.0);
            arrayBoxes.add(newBox);

            SelectBox select = new SelectBox(xBox, 0.0, yBox, 0.0);
            selectBoxes.add(0, select);

            mouseIsDown=true;

            mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);

        }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");


        element.addEventListener("mouseup", event -> {  // Draw Box on MouseUp

            Element boundingBoxResult2 = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult2);

            JsonObject evtData2 = event.getEventData();

            endX = evtData2.getNumber("event.x");
            endY = evtData2.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-x", String.format("%f", endX));
            boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-y", String.format("%f", endY));

//            System.out.println(endX);
//            System.out.println(endY);

            double xcoordi = 0;
            double ycoordi = 0;
            double boxWidth = 0;
            double boxHeight = 0;

//            for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(endX);
                System.out.println(endY);
                    arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).setWidth(endX, arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).xcoordi);
                    arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).setHeight(endY, arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).ycoordi);
                    xcoordi = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getXcoordi();
                    ycoordi = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getYcoordi();
                    boxWidth = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getWidth();
                    boxHeight = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getHeight();
                    boxCount++;


            mouseIsDown=false;

            context.beginPath();
            context.setStrokeStyle("green");
            context.setLineWidth(2);
            context.strokeRect(xcoordi, ycoordi, boxWidth, boxHeight);
            context.stroke();
            context.fill();



            SelectBox select = new SelectBox(endX, 0.0, endY, 0.0);
            selectBoxes.add(1, select);

//            if (selectBoxes.get(1).getSelectEndX() == selectBoxes.get(0).getSelectStartX()){
//                mouseSelect = true;
//                context.beginPath();
//                context.setStrokeStyle("yellow");
//                context.setLineWidth(2);
//                context.strokeRect(arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).ycoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxWidth, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxHeight);
//                context.fill();
//            }

            System.out.println(arrayBoxes.toString());
//
//            for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++){
//                if(arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi)
//                if (endX > arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi){
//                    if (endX < arrayBoxes.get(i).endY)
//                }
//            }

            mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);

        }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");

        element.addEventListener("mousemove", event -> {  // Retrieve Mouse Position when Moving

                JsonObject mousePos = event.getEventData();

                double mouseX = mousePos.getNumber("event.x");
                double mouseY = mousePos.getNumber("event.y");

                MousePosition currentPos = new MousePosition(mouseX, mouseY);
                mousePosArray.add(0, currentPos);
                setMousePosArray(mousePosArray);
            mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);

     }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");

    }


    public static void undoLast() {

        undoCalled = true;

        if (arrayBoxes.size() > 0) {
            arrayBoxes.remove(arrayBoxes.size() - 1);
        }
        System.out.println(arrayBoxes.toString());
        System.out.println(arrayBoxes.size());

        context.clearRect(0, 0, 1580, 700);
        context.drawImage("https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2016/10/Red-Clouds-and-Prairie-Background.jpg", 0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++){
            context.beginPath();
            context.setStrokeStyle("green");
            context.setLineWidth(2);
            context.strokeRect(arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).ycoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxWidth, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxHeight);
            context.fill();
        }

        boxCount--;
        System.out.println("Box Count: " + boxCount);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the context for rendering shapes and images in the canvas.
     * <p>
     * It is a Java wrapper for the <a href=
     * "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D">same
     * client-side API</a>.
     *
     * @return the 2D rendering context of this canvas
     */
    public CanvasRenderingContext2D getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> Canvas has an internal coordinate system that it uses for
     * drawing, and it uses the width and height provided in the constructor.
     * This coordinate system is independent of the component's size. Changing
     * the component's size with this method may scale/stretch the rendered
     * graphics.
     */
    @Override
    public void setWidth(String width) {
        HasSize.super.setWidth(width);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> Canvas has an internal coordinate system that it uses for
     * drawing, and it uses the width and height provided in the constructor.
     * This coordinate system is independent of the component's size. Changing
     * the component's size with this method may scale/stretch the rendered
     * graphics.
     */
    @Override
    public void setHeight(String height) {
        HasSize.super.setHeight(height);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> Canvas has an internal coordinate system that it uses for
     * drawing, and it uses the width and height provided in the constructor.
     * This coordinate system is independent of the component's size. Changing
     * the component's size with this method may scale/stretch the rendered
     * graphics.
     */
    @Override
    public void setSizeFull() {
        HasSize.super.setSizeFull();
    }

    public void addComponent(Label label) {
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is due to one or both of these issues

1. When drawing the image, you correctly wait for it to load before actually drawing it to the canvas (`image.onload = ...`). This means that your code might start loading the image, then it draws all the boxes, and then the image loads so that it is drawn on top.
2. You run the image drawing script on `beforeClientResponse`, which means it might get called after all the code for drawing the boxes is called.

The simplest solution, if you always want to have an image as the background, is to use two canvases on top of each other (with absolute positioning, for example). This way, you can always draw the images to the background canvas, and all boxes to the foreground canvas. A bonus of this is that you don't have to redraw the background even if you clear the foreground canvas.